# how do I use rspec to test instance methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have an instance method that would be invoked after creating a new instance of the class.

How do I test it in Rspec?  I use the following and get an error:

```
  let(:schedule) { ScheduleKaya.new('test-client-id') }
  let(:schedule) { schedule.create_recurring_event('test-keyword', 'slack') }
```

In other words, I want to create the instance.  Then I want to apply a method `create_recurring_event`.

My test wants to check if it assigned the variables to the instance.

```
it "has @keyword = test-keyword" do

     expect(schedule.keyword).to eq('test-keyword')

end
```

Because it makes a database call, I want to check the response back from the call to see if I get a status = 200.

But I can't seem to both create the instance and then apply the method.

**Question:**

What is the right way to test for an instance method, one that is applied after creating a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `let` block acts like a method and returns the return value of the last statement. Therefore just write both into the same block and ensure that the right value is returned:

```
let(:schedule) do
  schedule_kaya = ScheduleKaya.new('test-client-id')
  schedule_kaya.create_recurring_event('test-keyword', 'slack')
  schedule_kaya
end
```

Or you can use [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
let(:schedule) do
  ScheduleKaya.new('test-client-id').tap do |schedule_kaya|
    schedule_kaya.create_recurring_event('test-keyword', 'slack')
  end
end
```

Comment: Ahhh this is what I was looking for.

Comment: This is the first time I saw someone explain this this clearly after scouring the web on every article on rspec and let.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)  together with Rspec, if you are on Rails[factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails), looks like below:

```
it "has @keyword = test-keyword" do
  schedule = Factory(:shcedule, keyword: "has @keyword = test-keyword")
  expect(schedule.keyword).to eq('test-keyword')
end
```